# Kafka consumer behavior

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Trying to understand the wording from the kafka documentation regarding how the consumer gets access to the message.

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#theconsumer

From what I understand, if there is more than one consumer with the same consumer group message will be delivered to exactly one consumer with in a group. My question here is on the delivery mechanism referred in the line is PUSH or PULL? <s>If it's PUSH what is considered as delivered?(handing over semantics)</s>. If its a pull how does kafka makes sure each message is read by only one consumer (synchronization among consumers)? Thanks!

Comment: It says "pulled from the broker by the consumer". So it's definitely a PULL.

Comment: Yes, that's the impression I got but wanted to double check. Do you know the answer for the other part of the question.

Comment: Reading through it says "Consumers label themselves with a consumer group name, and each record published to a topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each subscribing consumer group. (...) If all the consumer instances have the same consumer group, then the records will effectively be load balanced over the consumer instances. If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then each record will be broadcast to all the consumer processes." 

Not sure it answers your doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If its a pull how does kafka makes sure each message is read by only one consumer?

It depends what you mean by "Kafka". Broker do not check anything because it's a *pull* model (ie, a broker delivers the data a consumer is requesting and does not care about anything else).

Thus, it is the consumers' responsibility to divide the work. For example using `KafkaConsumer`, all consumer instances talk to each other via "group management protocol" (this protocol is offered by the brokers; other, non-Java client also offer group management capabilities). This allows the instances to decide which one processed which topic partitions. Thus, each partition is assigned to exactly one consumer. It is basically a "contract": consumer instances talk to each other, and each consumer promises to only consume data from the partitions assigned to it.

If you want to know more, see the Kafka wiki: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+0.9+Consumer+Rewrite+Design